# Is there an issue on python 3.8 with gsheet batch_update?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

Following the following question and solution, [how to reset all rows and column data uisng python gspread sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015321/how-to-reset-all-rows-and-column-data-uisng-python-gspread-sheets),
I have the following exact code

```
requests = {"requests": [{"updateCells": {"range": {"sheetId": worksheet._properties['sheetId']}, "fields": "*"}}]}
res = spreadsheet.batch_update(requests)
```

but I am receiving the following error

```
File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 1171, in batch_update data = [ File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 1172, in <listcomp> dict(vr, range=absolute_range_name(self.title, vr['range'])) TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Anyone who has experienced this? and how did you resolve it?

Comment: About [your this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015321/how-to-reset-all-rows-and-column-data-uisng-python-gspread-sheets/60022818?noredirect=1#comment110843082_60022818), I found your question here. So I would like to propose the modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- Although, unfortunately, I cannot see your whole script in your question, from your error message, I thought that your issue might be that you are using `batch_update` method in class gspread.models.Worksheet. Because in my environment, when I tested the following script, I confirmed the same error with you.

  ```
    worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
    requests = {"requests": [{"updateCells": {"range": {"sheetId": worksheet._properties['sheetId']}, "fields": "*"}}]}
    res = worksheet.batch_update(requests)
    print(res)
  ```
- In this case, please use `batch_update` method in class gspread.models.Spreadsheet.

In order to remove this issue, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheetId = "###"  # Please set Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "###"  # Please set sheet name.
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
requests = {"requests": [{"updateCells": {"range": {"sheetId": worksheet._properties['sheetId']}, "fields": "*"}}]}
res = spreadsheet.batch_update(requests)
```

- Please set your authorization script.

#### Note:

- I tested above script with python 3.8.3 and gspread 3.6.0, and I could confirm that the script worked.

#### References:

- [batch_update in class gspread.models.Worksheet(spreadsheet, properties)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batch_update#gspread.models.Worksheet.batch_update)
- [batch_update in class gspread.models.Spreadsheet(client, properties)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batch_update#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update)